# Changing home environment variable in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I know this is a simple question but I have never done this before can someone help me out set up a home environment for eclipse. The reason I am doing this is because I am trying to implement one of maven projects and I keep getting the same error saying it can't find the jar.

Here is the message:

The environmental variable HOME is not set. The following directory will be used for storing the Git user configuration and as a default repository location: S:/. If this is not correct please set the HOME environment variable and restart Eclipse.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If this is on Windows you can set environment variables like here:

> <kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>Pause/Break</kbd> `-> Advanced system Settings -> Environment Variables`

Comment: what's win pause/break? it's windows but I don't see Winpausse/break

Comment: @Akyllite `Win` is you windows key and `Pause/Break` is your Puause/Break key. But you could skip that keyboard shortcut and go via `Control Panel -> System`

Answer (score 4):

Setting up the Home Directory on Windows

Add the environment variable HOME to your environment variables.

```
 1. In Windows 7, type "environment" at the start menu        
 2. Select "Edit environment variables for your account"
 3. Click the "New" button.
 4. Enter "HOME" in the name field
 5. Enter "%USERPROFILE%" or some other path in the value field.
 6. Click OK, and OK again. You have just added the Home directory on Windows.
```

e.g. `C:\Users\Tom` where tom is the %USERPROFILE%

**Note:** All letters are case sensitive so *c:\users\tom* and *C:\Users\Tom* are totally different in Windows.